# new changes on the Nextjs project does not run on the remote Server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cpanel, pm2

I have a simple Nextjs v13.5.6 project. I could run it locally and all things work fine. but when I upload my files into remote Cpanel and run the NodeJs application that I created already all things work again.

now suppose I added a new page called `about` in the local project and then uploaded related files to the server. now I go to the Terminal page in cpanel and run `npm run build` and `npm start` but **no things occurred**.

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "next": "13.5.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.5.6"
  }
}
```

I used PM2 and ran the `pm restart project-name` command but did not solve the problem.

I want to know how can I build and run a next.js project.

Comment: Does nobody have any suggestions about this problem?

Comment: I guess not - maybe some bounty would help. Or maybe people have moved off here to chatGPT and friends already...